# C++ RNG (Random Number Generation) Optimization

Tags: c++, random

First of all I'd like to clarify I'm quite new to C++, and I've put together some code that outputs a random set of 16 digits. For that I used a tutorial online and the comparatively higher batch experience (this idea came from a batch file that was running quite slowly and I wanted to migrate both batch files to c++ to compare how they ran, as there were two similar projects, one of them for random number generation, which is this one, and another for random string generation). As I'm not that great with c++, I'd like some help optimizing the code, as I feel it can be done in fewer lines
Now that you've got the background, my code is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    int random0 = 0;
    int random1 = 0;
    int random2 = 0;
    int random3 = 0;
    int random4 = 0;
    int random5 = 0;
    int random6 = 0;
    int random7 = 0;
    int random8 = 0;
    int random9 = 0;
    int random10 = 0;
    int random11 = 0;
    int random12 = 0;
    int random13 = 0;
    int random14 = 0;
    int random15 = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < i+1; ++i)
    {
        random0 = std::rand() % 9;
        random1 = std::rand() % 9;
        random2 = std::rand() % 9;
        random3 = std::rand() % 9;
        random4 = std::rand() % 9;
        random5 = std::rand() % 9;
        random6 = std::rand() % 9;
        random7 = std::rand() % 9;
        random8 = std::rand() % 9;
        random9 = std::rand() % 9;
        random10 = std::rand() % 9;
        random11 = std::rand() % 9;
        random12 = std::rand() % 9;
        random13 = std::rand() % 9;
        random14 = std::rand() % 9;
        random15 = std::rand() % 9;

        std::cout << random0 << random1 << random2 << random3 << random4 << random5 << random6 << random7 << random8 << random9 << random10 << random11 << random12 << random13 << random14 << random15 << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help, and I'm sorry if I trigger any experienced c++ coder's OCD.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Please read [ask].

Comment: @RichardCritten Yeah sorry about that, thought the title would be self-explainatory. Edited the body to specify what I needed... Basically just cleaning the code up, as I feel it has wayyy too many lines for what it does

Comment: @FranckTheMiner Have you learned about `std::vector`? If you find yourself requiring lots of variables with names differing only in numbers at the end, you probably want to have one `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @uneven_mark hey, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, as I said, I'm still pretty new (as in i'm 50% through the codecademy course), so even though I feel like I get the point of vector, I have no clue how to implement it in this case

Comment: You should not generate a random number digit by digit, generate a large number and print it.  Here is a starting point https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Answer (score 1):

> and I've put together some code that outputs a random set of 16 digits.

I read this as print a random number between `0` and `999999999999999`.
With a calculator I converted all the 9-s to `23 86F2 6FC0 FFFF` which is more than 32 bits but less than 64, so we can use `uint64_t`

Generating random numbers can be done with [`std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_int_distribution/), printing the generated number as 16 digits is a task for [`std::setw`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) and [`std::setfill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/?kw=setfill)

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;  
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); 
    uint64_t maxlim = 9999999999999999 ;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t> dis(0, maxlim);
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(16) << dis(gen) << std::endl;
}
```

*This is only valid for C++11 and later*

Comment: `std::cout << std::setfill('0')<<std::setw(16)<<dis(gen) << std::endl;` can be used to get the same output as in question.

Comment: Hey,
Won't be able to check how that acts, but I need it to output exactly 16 digits. Judging by the way you phrased it, I'm pretty sure yours outputs from 1 to 16 digits. Is there any way to fill the missing numbers with 0s if it happens?

Comment: yes with setw and set_fill I will update with this later today

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, that's just what I needed!

Comment: Hey, bonus question, how do I output the resulting string of characters to a text file? I know I can use ofstring, but I don't know how to integrate std::setfill and std::setw with it

Comment: `std::fstream myfile("myfilename", std::ios::out);` then you will get a stream `myfile` which you use exactly as `cout` `myfile << std::setw(4) << myint << std::endl;`